# How can I read just articles (with included images) online?

Tags: browser, accessibility

I would like to read just the contents of an article (text plus images) on a website (any modern news/blog website) spanned over the entire width of my browser window.
I have installed browser addons such as `Clearly` for Google Chrome or `Reader` for Mozilla Firefox but I'm unsatisfied with their results (article does not span the entire width, loading is slow, images not always showing up or displayed too small or wrongly positioned).
Are there any other/online ways to achieve similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Google Mobilizer](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/10/read-proxied-mobile-friendly-web-pages.html)

As the Google Mobilizer service works by taking a querystring as an input, it can be [adapted to work like a search provider in Chrome](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2011/12/fastest-dictionary-on-web.html) & [Opera](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/10/adding-new-search-provider-easiest-with.html), to simplify its use.  The string to use for configuring it is -
**`http://www.google.com/gwt/x?noimg=1&btnGo=Go&source=wax&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&u=%s`**

If you assign a letter like M to this app, you can type M in the Chrome address bar/omnibox & then the type the URL you would like to see via Google Mobilizer.

Change the value for **noimg** in the querystring to 0 to view images in the article.

Comment: that's the closest to what I imagined (and later the night I asked found it myself but forgot to improve the question :) - any idea though how to disable breaking the document into separate pages? apparently (in order to keep the page small for mobile, I presume) the original article is broken down by google into separate pages and reading implies clicking "next page" until the end.

Comment: i wonder if there is a querystring parameter to do that. do not know if there is some developer documentation on Google Mobilizer.

Answer (score 0):

[Pocket](http://www.getpocket.com) may do what you want. Try saving the article to your pocket account and reading it there.

Comment: I will try that - though I'd prefer a loginless service (=fewer clicks)